# Get HTML output after processing a single CQ component

Tags: java, aem

We currently have a homepage with several CQ components written in JSP. As HTML page renders, each component is processed to get its HTML output from JSP. Homepage will aggregate the outputs into a single HTML.

At the moment, I want to get HTML output of one particular CQ component in the homepage and pass it elsewhere. The HTML output must be the result of processing its JSP file, any required input values will be provided.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A component is a resource, so it can be rendered on its own. Let's say there is a component "x" included on the home page:

```
<cq:include path="x" resourceType="foo"/>`
```

- To get x's output alone the URL would be `homepage/jcr:content/x.html`.
- If it's in a parsys with a path of 'par', then the URL would become `homepage/jcr:content/par/x.html`.

The output you get will be the processed output of the component's JSP (renderer), however it is very unlikely that it'll look like how it looks when it's part of the whole page. This is because CSS is mostly loaded in the page component's JSP.

If your component has its own clientlib included in its JSP and it's styled to work without container divs then it would work on its own.

Comment: based on this answer, you could build a separate page with its own url and the required CSS, and if needed JS, included and in the <body> you just have the cq:include whereas the path is dynamic, eg. <cq:include path="<%=pathToMyComponent%>" resourceType="myResourceType"/>

Comment: Hi Sharath, Is this possible to make the content visible on same page using this like I have `<div id="content"> <cq:include path="parsys" resourceType="foundation/components/parsys"/> </div>
<div id="footer">  <cq:include path="replicate" resourceType="${currentPage.name}/jcr:content/parsys/editbehaviour.html" /></div>`  I drop the editbehaviour component in parsys and want to replicate its behavior via cq:include . Is this possible, as i tried it not rendering the content. Thanks

Comment: Use sling include if you want to render the component for the second time without edit functionality.  If the component has been included like `<cq:include path="x" resourceType="foo"/>` then do `<sling:include path="x" resourceType="foo">` , this will render the component again minus edit capabilities and will display what ever you configure via the cq:included component. cq:include withsame path should work too, only the first instance will be editable. However sling include will let you add selectors in case you want a different rendering script

Comment: @SharathMadappa:Now i am using <div id="footer">  <sling:include path="editbehaviour" resourceType="${currentPage.name}/jcr:content/parsys/editbehaviour.html" /></div> . & Can see in my browser console <!--cq{"decorated":false,"type":"testpage/jcr:content/parsys/editbehaviour.html","path":"/content/aemproject/en/testpage/jcr:content/editbehaviour","selectors":null,"servlet":"DefaultGetServlet","totalTime":0,"selfTime":0}--> under footer. But if i hit http://localhost:4502/content/aemproject/en/testpage/jcr:content/parsys/editbehaviour.html it shows me content for that component.

Comment: You have mixed up path n resource type , the correct syntax for this case is   <sling:include path="parsys/editbehaviour" resourceType="</apps/your project/.../thisComponent>" />

Comment: Thank you. Just for completeness, when we have URL http://localhost/content/mytest/home/jcr:content/par-col-body/col/mytest_component to get the content on browser we append it with .html as follow: http://localhost/content/mytest/home/jcr:content/par-col-body/col/mytest_component.html